# How to organise tabs in the Xfce Panel by workspace?

Tags: software-recommendation, xfce, workspaces, panel, window-management

I am constantly using multiple workspaces for different types of programs and I would like to have them all visible on my Xfce Panel.

The "tasklist" plugin has the option to show open tabs from all workspaces, but it does not organise them in any way, so just by looking at it, I don't know what program is openend on which workspace.

Then, I recently saw this screenshot:

[image]

After testing all available plugins, I found out that the "windowmenu" can show all tabs sorted by workspaces, just like the Panel in the screenshot. However, it only does this after pressing a button that has to be added to the Panel first.

How can I have my Panel show open tabs similar to the one in the screenshot? (It does no have to reserve space for all workspaces, just sort them by which virtual desktop they're on.)

Answer (score 0):

You try to set this behaviour for the `Window Buttons` plugin.

In the panel settings go to the `Items` tab.

Edit preferences for the `Windows Buttons` plugin - there are several filtering options.

Mark `Show Windows from all workspaces or viewports`

Comment: Well, this does not sort the windows by workspace though. So the first tab could be on workspace 1, the second on 3 and the third on 2 without manually organising them. The goal would be to have them sorted by workspaces, as seen on the screenshot I posted.